# Pandas count of sequence of positive and negative numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Problem is probably simple, but my brain doesn't work as expected.

Imagine you have this Panda Series:

```
y = pd.Series([5, 5 , -5 , -10, 7 , 7 ])
z = y * 0
```

I would like to have output:

```
1, 2 , -1 ,-2 ,1 ,2
```

My solution below:

```
for i, row in y.iteritems():
if i == 0 and y[i] > 0:
    z[i] = 1
elif i == 0:
    z[i] = -1
elif y[i] >= 0 and y[i-1] >= 0:
    z[i] = 1 + z[i-1]
elif y[i] < 0 and y[i-1] < 0:
    z[i] = -1 + z[i-1]
elif y[i] >= 0 and y[i-1] < 0:
    z[i] = 1
elif y[i]  < 0 and y[i-1] >= 0:
    z[i] = -1
```

I would think there is a more Python/Panda solution.

Comment: Look up [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.sign()` to check if the number is positive/negative ans compare it to the next row using `shift()`. Finally, use `cumcount()` to sum each sub series

```
y = pd.Series([5, 5 , -5 , -10, 7 , 7 ])
parts = (np.sign(y) != np.sign(y.shift())).cumsum()
print((y.groupby(parts).cumcount() + 1) * np.sign(y))
# or print(y.groupby(parts).cumcount().add(1).mul(np.sign(y)))
```

Output

```
0    1
1    2
2   -1
3   -2
4    1
5    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning points in terms of sign are found via looking at difference not being 0 when subjected to `np.sign`. Then cumulative sum of this gives consecutive groups of same sign. We lastly put `cumcount` to number each group and also multiply by the sign to get negative counts:

```
signs = np.sign(y)
grouper = signs.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
result = y.groupby(grouper).cumcount().add(1).mul(signs)
```

where `add(1)` is because `cumcount` gives 0, 1, .. but we need 1 more.

```
>>> result

0    1
1    2
2   -1
3   -2
4    1
5    2
```